# What addition study subjects are required in the investment field

Tags: investment, self-study

Being a CFA student, for example, I feel I need an additional course in statistics and math, but I've never worked in the field. And maybe, as a specialist working in the profession for some time you can suggest other required subjects related to the field that I am underestimating now?

P.S. I concern that the real life differs from what I think of it as a student. So I want to do my best to be a specialist to the end of my education.

Comment: i am waiting for the answers from people with real experience in the investment.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is meant to host questions about the subject of economics rather than career advice.